# Replace item in list with corresponding item in another list (Python)

Tags: python, list

I am working with a GA and need to modify the genome.  I have set the minimum value in the genome to be a "flag" indicating a random process.  So, while the function takes inputs in the inclusive range [0,8], the GA will only select values [4,8].  Any instance of "4" needs to be replaced with a number from another list that will be [0,4].

I currently achieve this using the following code:

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def modify_chromosome(chromosome):
    # If value == replace option, replace from another list
    for (index,value) in enumerate(chromosome):
        # Note "<=" necessary in case GA mutates the values
        if value <= flag_option:
            chromosome[index] = changed_value[index]
    # This changes the actual chromosome in the GA
    return chromosome
```

Where the changed_value list is previously defined as

```
changed_value = random.randint(0,flag_option,len(num_entries))
```

The code above works fine, but iterating through a list like this is very time consuming (~10% of the overall run time is in this function).

**My Question:**
Is there a more efficient way of implementing the above block of code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Surely whatever you do, you're going to have to iterate?

Comment: Questions about improving working code are a better fit for [codereview.se].

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi & zmo : Thank you, I was not aware of that site.  Apologies for using the wrong forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best you could do is iterate over both lists using `izip` so that you don't create the `index` list every time you run the `enumerate(chromosome)` command.

```
from itertools import izip

changed_value = random.randint(0,flag_option,len(num_entries))
chromosome = [c if c <= flag_option else v  
                for c, v in izip(chromosome, changed_value)]
```

**EDIT :** So I have down some benchmark test using the following script:

```
from itertools import izip
import random
import timeit

def test_setup(n, flag_option=4):
    setup = 'from itertools import izip\nfrom random import randint\n'
    setup += 'flag_option = {}\n'.format(flag_option)
    setup += 'changed_val = [randint(0, flag_option) for _ in xrange({})]\n'.format(n)
    setup += 'chromosome = [randint(0, 8) for _ in xrange({})]\n'.format(n)
    return setup

test_izip  = '[v if c <= flag_option else c '
test_izip += 'for c, v in izip(chromosome, changed_val)]'

test_zip   = '[v if c <= flag_option else c '
test_zip  += 'for c, v in zip(chromosome, changed_val)]'

test_enum  = '[changed_val[i] if c <= flag_option else c '
test_enum += 'for i,c in enumerate(chromosome)]'

test_orig  = 'for (i,c) in enumerate(chromosome):\n'
test_orig += '\tif c <= flag_option:\n'
test_orig += '\t\tchromosome[i] = changed_val[i]'

if '__main__' == __name__:
    for n in [10 ** i for i in xrange(7)]:    
        print 'izip {}: '.format(n),
        print min(timeit.Timer(test_izip, setup=test_setup(n)).repeat(7, 1000))

        print 'zip {}: '.format(n),
        print min(timeit.Timer(test_zip, setup=test_setup(n)).repeat(7, 1000))   

        print 'enum {}: '.format(n),
        print min(timeit.Timer(test_enum, setup=test_setup(n)).repeat(7, 1000))   

        print 'orig {}: '.format(n),
        print min(timeit.Timer(test_orig, setup=test_setup(n)).repeat(7, 1000)) 

        print
```

The results are as follows:

```
izip 10:  0.00132203102112
zip 10:   0.00159502029419
enum 10:  0.00130820274353
orig 10:  0.000921964645386

izip 100:  0.00951504707336
zip 100:   0.01145195961
enum 100:  0.00957798957825
orig 100:  0.00854301452637

izip 1000:  0.0860891342163
zip 1000:   0.109489917755
enum 1000:  0.0958349704742
orig 1000:  0.0862739086151

izip 10000:  0.922410964966
zip 10000:   1.31961488724
enum 10000:  1.00453591347
orig 10000:  0.93142914772

izip 100000:  9.61347794533 
zip 100000:  18.9829239845
enum 100000: 10.6979219913
orig 100000:  9.5124809742

izip 1000000:  100.970448971
zip 1000000:   211.297281027
enum 1000000:  122.404583931
orig 1000000:   94.8837227821
```

So after everything, it looks like your original code would be the fastest.

Comment: I don't want to generate the randint each pass through as that will yield a different functional result.  ///


There is a chance I will be replacing the same values out, yes (a 3=>3 for instance).  However, since the GA will "mutate" the inputs occasionally, I do not want to allow a 2=>3.  ///


The inputs represent "action", where 5-8 are "positive actions" and a "4" denotes "no action".  I am replacing "no action" with "random bad event" (4 options).  I want the "bad event" to be constant for the optimization process, but random at each location --- hence the changed_value list.

Comment: How is that condition guarantee in the first case if it is generated ahead of time? could you use `random.randint(c,flag_option)` instead?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  My intention is to ensure the same _bad event_ occurs at each location if _no action_ is selected.  By replacing an entry in the chromosome `c` with a randomly generated number, each iteration will have a different _bad event_ replacement value.  By pre-generating the list of `changed_value`, I ensure that through the ~10K iterations, every time _no action_ is selected, the same _bad event_ occurs at that node.

Comment: This might help then.

Comment: Thanks.  I'd +1 but I don't have the rep yet.  Appreciate you sticking with it.

Comment: actually, I just ran timings and using izip is about 15% slower.  I did the operation 10,000 times on a 1000 length array and found the following: `enumerate: 11.70804`; `izip: 13.36707`

Comment: If you are dealing with times that are that short of scale the creation of the iterator might not be worth it then. I thought your delay was much longer. Just out of curiosity, how long would it take using `zip` instead of `izip`?

Comment: I created a test program to compare the various methods.  The actual code uses a list ~1300 elements that must be queried ~800K times.  So, a 20% speedup in that instance is on the order of minutes.  Izip is slightly faster, but enumerate definitely wins:

`Enumerate: 12.100632`;
`Zip: 13.972002`;
`IZip: 13.796025`

Comment: I don't know how you are getting numbers so large with just 1300 elements. Take a look at the benchmarks I just posted. Also, are you saying that your GA is taking nearly 800k iteration to converge to the optimal solution?

Comment: For my benchmarks, I was just doing what you did repeated 10k times. Good to see we found the sane results. The GA does not need 800k iterations, no, sorry. I give it 5-10k iterations but optimize 11 different scenarios, leading to several hundred thousand calls. Thanks again for sticking with this.